# ruby round integer to nearest multiple of 5

Tags: ruby

I want to take an integer and round it up to the next multiple of 5. Like such:

```
input:    output:
0    ->   0
2    ->   5
3    ->   5
12   ->   15
21   ->   25
30   ->   30
-2   ->   0
-5   ->   -5
etc.
```

My function below accounts for the numbers that are divisible by 10, but I have no idea how to do it for the numbers divisible by 5. This is what I have so far;

```
    def round_to_next_5(n)
      if n % 5 == 0
        return n
      else 
        return n.round(-1)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Divide by 5, add 1 and multiply by 5? For negatives don't add the 1.

Answer (score 19):

One could write `(16/5.0).ceil * 5 #=> 20` but round-off is a problem for large integers:

```
(1000000000000001/5.0).ceil * 5
  #=> 1000000000000005   # correct
(10000000000000001/5.0).ceil * 5
  #=> 10000000000000000  # incorrect
```

For that reason I'd prefer to stick with integer operations.

```
def round_up(n, increment)
  increment * (( n + increment - 1) / increment)
end

(-10..15).each { |n| puts "%s=>%s" % [n, round_up(n,5)] }

-10=>-10
 -9=> -5  -8=>-5  -7=>-5  -6=>-5  -5=>-5
 -4=>  0  -3=> 0  -2=> 0  -1=> 0   0=> 0
  1=>  5   2=> 5   3=> 5   4=> 5   5=> 5
  6=> 10   7=>10   8=>10   9=>10  10=>10
 11=> 15  12=>15  13=>15  14=>15  15=>15
```

Answer (score 11):

This is the simplest solution I can come up with (and very much like your implementation)

```
def up_to_nearest_5(n)
  return n if n % 5 == 0
  rounded = n.round(-1)
  rounded > n ? rounded : rounded + 5
end
```

When `Integer#round` is given a negative number it rounds the nth (`1` in this case) least significant digit as if it were the decimal value. eg

```
1254.round(-1) 
#=> 1250
1254.round(-2)
#=> 1300
```

So we just see if the number is a factor of 5 if so return it otherwise, if it rounded up then return the rounded number or if it rounded down return the rounded number + 5.

However you can also use the `BigDecimal` standard library for precision math such that the method would look like

```
require 'bigdecimal'
def up_to_nearest_5(n)
  BigDecimal(n)./(5).ceil * 5
end
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even think about using rounded + 5, it makes it easier for sure

Answer (score 4):

Build your method out of this expression: `(44 / 5.0).round(0) * 5.0`. It returns `45.0` for me.

Comment: Should probably use `.ceil` instead of round, and multiply by `5`, not `5.0`. There is no indication OP wants a float.

Comment: Edit your post, and add your version with `.ceil` and your error message.

Comment: Perfect, I'll have a look

Comment: This is wrong. OP wanted 21 -> 25, this gives 21 -> 20.0

Answer (score 2):

There are a few correct solutions already posted, but here's mine which does no multiplication/division - only one modulo (should in theory run faster, but that wasn't my goal):

```rb
def round_up_to_multiple_of(n, m)
  (n - 1) + m - (n - 1) % m
end

p [0, 2, 3, 12, 21, 30, -2, -5].map { |n| [n, round_up_to_multiple_of(n, 5)] }
#=> [[0, 0], [2, 5], [3, 5], [12, 15], [21, 25], [30, 30], [-2, 0], [-5, -5]]
```

Here's how to round down to the nearest multiple (which is what I was trying to do and found this question):

```rb
def round_down_to_multiple_of(n, m)
  (n + 1) - (n + 1) % m
end

p [0, 2, 3, 12, 21, 30, -2, -5].map { |n| [n, round_down_to_multiple_of(n, 5)] }
#=> [[0, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [12, 10], [21, 20], [30, 30], [-2, -5], [-5, -5]]
```

Comment: Any reason why modulo should be faster? Not arguing because I didn't bother to benchmark but the docs state "`x.modulo(y)` means `x-y*(x/y).floor` equivalent to `num.divmod(numeric)[1]`" so the division and multiplication are implied by modulo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code for solving this:

```
def to_nearest_5(int)
    until -int%5 == 0
        int += 1
    end
    return int
end
```

For an array of integers:

```
def to_nearest_5(arr)
    arr.each do |int|
        until -int%5 == 0
            int += 1
        end
        return int
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to [Cary Swoveland's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51275735/750452).

```
def round_to_nearest(n, increment)
  increment * ((n + increment/2.0).to_i / increment)
end

# nearest 4
[-10.0, -7.0, 1.1, 2.4, 2.5,3.0, 4.5, 5.3, 5.5, 6.5, 7.4, 7.5,8.5, 9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5,15.0].map { |n| [n, round_to_nearest(n, 4)] }
=> [[-10.0, -8], [-7.0, -8], [1.1, 0], [2.4, 4], [2.5, 4], [3.0, 4], [4.5, 4], [5.3, 4], [5.5, 4], [6.5, 8], [7.4, 8], [7.5, 8], [8.5, 8], [9.5, 8], [10.5, 12], [11.5, 12], [12.5, 12], [15.0, 16]]

# nearest 5
[-10.0, -7.0, 1.1, 2.4, 2.5,3.0, 4.5, 5.3, 5.5, 6.5, 7.4, 7.5,8.5, 9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5,15.0].map { |n| [n, round_to_nearest(n, 5)] }
=> [[-10.0, -10], [-7.0, -5], [1.1, 0], [2.4, 0], [2.5, 5], [3.0, 5], [4.5, 5], [5.3, 5], [5.5, 5], [6.5, 5], [7.4, 5], [7.5, 10], [8.5, 10], [9.5, 10], [10.5, 10], [11.5, 10], [12.5, 15], [15.0, 15]]
```