# Rails round currency to nearest 5 cents with `number_to_currency`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency, currency-formatting

Rails does a great job when it comes to providing view helpers that are internationally useful. This applies to currencies as well, using the helper `number_to_currency`. However, per documentation, I cannot find how to adjust that helper to a special case, the Swiss Franc (CHF).

The problem with the currency CHF is that the smallest coin is 5 cents, i.e. the smallest steps are CHF 1.00, 1.05, 1.10, 1.15 and so on. There is no such thing as 1.01.

The obvious solution here would be to multiply by 2, round, and divide by 2 again. However, I have a hope that `number_to_currency`, which is otherwise so potent, should be able to tackle this as well. Is this the case?

Comment: This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274453/ruby-round-integer-to-nearest-multiple-of-5/) can help you with the rounding part. `number_to_currency` is just a string formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, `number_to_currency` is a string formatter. You're looking for something else, not related to presentation but to making the actual number valid in your Swiss currency context.

So I would just extend the `Float` class like this:

```rb
class Float
  def rounded_to_5_cents
    ((self*2).round(1))/2
  end
end
# number_to_currency((55.03).rounded_to_5_cents, unit: "CHF") => CHF55.05
```

Answer (score 1):

Rounding is not [one of the options](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) available on the method.

I'd suggest rounding the number before passing it to the `number_to_currency` method as the return value is a `String`.